# Is there a way to play a local mp3 with soundmanager2?

Tags: input, mp3, local, soundmanager2

I want the user to pick a mp3 file using a 
`<input type="file" name="myFile">`
and play it on the browser (preferably with soundmanager2).
Thing is I don't want to send the file to my server.
I'd very much like to do so locally, with javascript/jQuery.
Have anyone done something like it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a server.

Without a server (apache or any other) you will get in troubles trying to find the local path of the user file.

Anyway, it's not possible to get the full path of a file with javascript due to security restrictions of the browsers.